# Updating constraint at runtime fail

Tags: ios, swift, runtime, constraints

In my App I'm trying to update the priority of two constraints depends on clicking on the button.

first time I clicked on the button the constraint updated, the second time the constraints didn't update,

but the surprise is when I captured the view hierarchy the saw that the view is updated right!

and when I leave the view and return to it I found the constraints updated right!!!

I updated the constraints on clicking on button like this way:

```
if clicked {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {

        self.pagerButtomConstraintWithCancelButton.priority = 500
        self.pagerBottomConstraintWithDriverInfo.priority = 100
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    clicked = false 
} else {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {

        self.pagerButtomConstraintWithCancelButton.priority = 100
        self.pagerBottomConstraintWithDriverInfo.priority = 500
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


    })
    clciked = true 
}
```

anyone faced like this problem?

I really give up on this problem, two days without any solutions.

Thanks alot.

Comment: What do you mean with "second time"? You set these constraints to constant values, tapping the button twice on the same screen should update them only once, unless there is a kind of a reset method which you didn't show and tell us about :)

Comment: @Losiowaty ohh sorry, I perform two functions, this is the second one :D 
I'll update my question

Comment: And how do you decide between this two versions? Can you show the whole button handler?

Comment: @Losiowaty I updated my answer

Comment: it sounds like `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` is the wrong view that is being called on, for the constraints to update with animation, the superview of the view the constraints are tied to needs that method called, but im not sure what your layout looks like so it could be right and is in fact something else